# cd to symbolic link in linux shows error

Tags: posix, symlink

```
XXXXX:~/a/n1$ ln -s n1 n
XXXXX:~/a/n1$ ls
bin      doc  n  nc.tcsh  packages  scripts  support  VERSION
XXXXX:~/a/n1$ cd n
bash: cd: n: No such file or directory
```

I am creating a sym link to n1 which is n.
Now when i do a cd in bash or shell i am not able to.

What is missing.

Comment: `~/a/n1/n1` doesn't exist

Comment: Dead links are usually detected and highlighted **red** (at least in bash) by typing 'ls -la' in the directory where you created the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making a symlink is done as `ln -s target linkname`.

The target "n1" does not exists in your current directory, but the link will nevertheless been made, allbeit a dead link. When you create a subdirectory "n1" in the current directory (like `mkdir n1`), the link will no longer be dead.

If you meant to make a symlink to the current directory ".", then the command is: `ln -s . n`. Note that this will make it recursive, making `cd n/n/n/n/` possible.

Comment: Alternatively: `ln -s ../n1 n` (or `ln -s ${PWD} n` for a full path link - although that's somewhat less efficient...).

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Here's my RL example: `ln -s ~/Library/Android/ androidsdk` You say create a directory to remove dead link, `mkdir androidsdk`, console error: `mkdir: androidsdk: File exists`. If someone could clarify, that'd be awesome. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your "ls" there is now "n1" file shown. You can create a symlink to a directory that doesn't exist, but you can't then "cd" into it... the source directory still doesn't exist. :)

You *can*, however, make a symlink to a non-existent file and then edit that the file through the symlink. The source file will appear when you save, just like editing any new file.

Comment: Is there more to this post?

Answer (score 0):

A symlink can be created using an absolute or a relative path.

In your scenario, you want to use an absolute path. That can be done by prefixing your source folder with `$PATH`. In other words, run:

```bash
ln -s $PATH/n1 n

cd n
ls -la
```

Comment: fyi you're answering a question that's nearly a decade old (and already has an accepted answer). Plus... the question is off-topic.