# Symlink is not present but it is there

Tags: macos, path, posix, symlink

I want to create a symlink under the folder
`[/xyz/env]` but when I try to create by running `ln -s ../_env/WorkSupport-salt3ja.2332122.412986533.123456789 WorkSupport` under the previous above folder it create the path, but with the red colour, and my understanding is when it show with red colour means it is a dead symlink.

and I got `no such file or directory: WorkSupport`

Please help what I am missing here?

Related question, but not solve my issue: [cd to symbolic link in linux shows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837526/cd-to-symbolic-link-in-linux-shows-error)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for question about programming, not general computer usage; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) or the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) would be better places to ask about this. But... is there a file at `/xyz/_env/WorkSupport-salt3ja.2332122.412986533.123456789`?

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson , Seems like no file created at `/xyz/_env/WorkSupport-salt3ja.2332122.412986533.123456789`.